# Solving $-\sin x - \sin8x = \sin9x$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the easiest way to solve this trigonometric equation?

$$-\sin x - \sin8x = \sin9x$$

This is what I did but its ugly: $$-\sin4.5x\cos3.5x = \sin4.5x\cos4.5x$$

Is there any way to avoid decimal numbers like those 4.5 and 3.5?

Comment: Ever heard about fractions?

Comment: @Bernard Can u tell me please, how fractions is used here?

Comment: why donot you use sinx+sin9x=sin8x= 2sin4x cos4x

Comment: $4.5=\dfrac92$ and $3.5=\dfrac72$, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** make $\sin(9x)+\sin(x)=-\sin(8x)$.

Then use $$\sin(a)+\sin(b)=2\sin\frac{1}{2}(a+b)\cos\frac{1}{2}(a-b)$$

and even the double angle fomula

This will  then give $$2\sin(5x)\cos(4x)=-\sin(8x)=-2\sin(4x)\cos(4x)$$

Rearrange from here.

Comment: @LiziPizi, See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that the both sides in what you did have $\sin\frac{9x}{2}$.$$-\sin x-\sin 8x=\sin 9x$$
$$-2\sin \frac{9 x}{2}\cos\frac{7 x}{2}=2\sin\frac{9x}{2}\cos\frac{9x}{2}$$
$$\sin\frac{9x}{2}\left(\cos\frac{9x}{2}+\cos\frac{7x}{2}\right)=0$$
$$\sin\frac{9x}{2}\times 2\cos(4x)\cos\frac{x}{2}=0$$
I think you can take it from here.

Comment: I was asking if there is a way to avoid decimal numbers, but ty anyway

Comment: @LiziPizi $\frac 92$ is a fraction, until you choose to write it out as a decimal number.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Correct, anyway I think I can't avoid both fracs or dec.

Comment: You can.  See Jack's answer. Maybe ask him to clarify what he means.

Answer (score 0):

use $\sin x+\sin9x=-\sin8x=-\sin4x \cos4x$ & $\sin x+\sin9x=\sin5x.\cos4x$ 
$(\sin2\alpha=2\sin\alpha \cos\alpha)$